MediaRouter Route Discovery Lag
I'm initializing a mediaRouter Instance and adding the callbacks. But the Route Discovery takes a little over 2 minutes.   Currently the MediaRouter  is set to  MediaRouter.CallbackFlagPerformActiveScan, but I've tried "MediaRouter.CallbackFlagForceDiscovery" and it doesn't seem to make a difference.   I did a break down on the times during start up the are as follows.

MediaRouter Initialization: 2024-06-13 09:05:23.113 - MediaRouter and MediaRouteSelector initialized successfully
CastContext Initialization: 2024-06-13 09:05:23.580 - CastContext initialized successfully
Route Added: 2024-06-13 09:07:02.394 - Route Added -- 6/13/2024 9:07:02 AM --

There is over a 2 Minute Lage between the time the MediaRouter is initalized and when the first route is added?   Any thoughts as to wy
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InitializeMediaRouteAsync()
  {
      await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
      {
          try
          {
              RunOnUiThread(() =>
              {
                  // Initialize MediaRouter and MediaRouteSelector
                  MediaRouterInstance = MediaRouter.GetInstance(ApplicationContext);
                  MediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                      .AddControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.CategoryForCast("7AA05E47"))
                      .Build();

                  // Add the callback to listen for route selections
                  MediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback(this);
                  MediaRouterInstance.AddCallback(MediaRouteSelector, MediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CallbackFlagPerformActiveScan);
                  Log.Debug("MainActivity", $"{GetTimestamp()} - MediaRouter and MediaRouteSelector initialized successfully.");
              });
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Log.Error("MainActivity", $"{GetTimestamp()} - Exception in InitializeMediaRouteAsync: " + ex.Message);
          }
      });
  }

